# How to execute command on Procfile?

Tags: php, heroku, cron, procfile

i want to ask about Procfile.

i want to make something like cron job, because i'm using heroku to deploy my app. and i can't use cron job in heroku.

i've tried this on my Procfile, but it didn't work.

Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
clock: php cron.php heroku:schedule:run
```

but not working. the cron.php is not executed.
i want to make the cron.php is executed when app deployed.

cron.php

```
<?php

$appRoot    = "https://myapiwebsite.zzz";
$cmd        = "curl $appRoot/check/action";
$sleep      = 30;
 
while (true) {
    exec($cmd);
    sleep($sleep);
}
```

any better solution?
please help. thank you.

sorry for bad english.